# Edit .htaccess to redirect from folder to html file

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, nested

A website is accessible via www.mydomain.com/blog/index.html

but I want it to be sufficient to type www.mydomain.com/blog

I know about .htaccess, how do I have to edit it to redirect the requests?

What I tried so far (without success) is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com/blog$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ blog/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a trailing slash in directories otherwise it causes an information disclosure issue where people can see the contents of a folder regardless of there being an index.html file in there. If you're not worried about the trailing slash, then all you need is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*)index\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

But if you **must** remove the trailing slash and open up your website to possible directory listings, then you can try something like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.*?)/?index\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L]
```